# Input type for HTML form for integer

Tags: html

The code below is from an HTML form.  If the input is supposed to be an integer, do I need to change the "type'?

```
<div class="friend2title">
    <label for="url">Add points:</label>
</div> 
<div class="friend2field">
    <input name="state" type="text" id="state" maxlength="150">
</div>
```

Comment: Which browser versions do you need to support?

Answer (score 44):

```
<input type="number" step="1" ...
```

By adding the `step` attribute, you restrict input to integers.

Of course you should always validate on the server as well. Except under carefully controlled conditions, everything received from a client needs to be treated as suspect.

Comment: It must be noted that this answer is valid only for HTML5

Comment: @PetrPeller It may depend. From [MDN imput number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number#Allowing_decimal_values) `Allowing decimal values

One issue with number inputs is that their step size is 1 by default — if you try to enter a number with a decimal, such as "1.0", it will be considered invalid. If you want to enter a value that requires decimals, you'll need to reflect this in the step value (e.g. step="0.01" to allow decimals to two decimal places). Here's a simple example:`

Comment: You can still add decimal places with this solution. Not cool.

Comment: Agree this doesn't force integer entry. It only forces the increment/decrement amount.

Answer (score 33):

This might help:

```
<input type="number" step="1" pattern="\d+" />
```

`step` is for convenience (and could be set to another integer), but `pattern` does some actual enforcing.

Note that since `pattern` matches the whole expression, it wasn't necessary to express it as `^\d+$`.

Even with this outwardly tight regular expression, Chrome and Firefox's implementations, interestingly allow for `e` here (presumably for scientific notation) as well as `-` for negative numbers, and Chrome also allows for `.` whereas Firefox is tighter in rejecting unless the `.` is followed by 0's only. (Firefox marks the field as red upon the input losing focus whereas Chrome doesn't let you input disallowed values in the first place.)

Since, as observed by others, one should always validate on the server (or on the client too, if using the value locally on the client or wishing to prevent the user from a roundtrip to the server).

Comment: While Chrome does not, in Firefox, adding the `pattern` ensures any use of a fractional portion gets the field marked as invalid.

Comment: Doesn't prevent decimal places from being entered. 12.5 is NOT an integer.

Comment: It doesn't prevent them from being entered but it does prevent them from being submitted (and will report as much when the user tries to submit), as it will make the validity state invalid (in both Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: But that does appear to be enforced differently from when I wrote the post--from my limited testing, it seems type "number" may be enough to require it to be an integer.

Answer (score 21):

If you're using HTML5, you should use the input type `number`. If you are using xhtml or html 4, input type should be `text`.

Comment: And then validate that you actually *got* a number. Yeah.

Comment: Okay... how can I tell if I'm using HTML 5?

Comment: @John You could just use `number`; it will of course fail HTML 4 validation but HTML 4 browsers will treat it as type `text`.

Comment: @ Neil... is HTML 5 determined by the visitor's browser?

Comment: @John HTML5 is a spec. If you use `<!doctype html>` before all other tags, it will tell the browser you are using HTML5. If the browser does not support HTML5, it will revert to HTML 4 and treat it as `text` like Neil said.

Comment: Note that type number will accept floating point numbers with 'e' or 'E' so you still have to validate against integer. http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html

Comment: This does not answer the question how to request an *integer*

Answer (score 5):

What about this:

```
<input type="number" step="1" onchange="this.value = parseInt(this.value);">
```

It just **takes whatever you wrote, and tries to make an integer** out of it (if it can't make an integer it will just leave it blank).

Also, let's say you're asking for numbers between 0 and 20:

```
<input type="number" step="1" onchange="this.value = Math.max(0, Math.min(20, parseInt(this.value)));">
```

This way you prevent people from writing numbers outside of the boundary (which is **not** prevented by your standard `min=` and `max=`).

Answer (score 2):

Prior to HTML5, **input type="text"** simply means a field to insert free text, regardless of what you want it be. that is the job of validations you would have to do in order to guarantee the user enters a valid number

If you're using HTML5, you can use the new input types, one of which is **number** that automatically validates the text input, and forces it to be a number

keep in mind though, that if you're building a server side app (php for example) you will still have to validate the input on that side (make sure it is really a number) since it's pretty easy to hack the html and change the input type, removing the browser validation

Comment: Setting type to "number" does not prevent '.' and 'e' characters, so it does not only allow integers.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your type to number
If you accept decimals first and remove them on keyUp, you might solve this...

```
$("#state").on('keyup', function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(".", ''));
})
```

or

```
$("#state").on('keyup', function(){
    $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val()));
})
```

This will remove the period, but there is no 'Integer Type'.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not about the data type of input. It specifies the [type of control to create](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#input-control-types):

> type = text|password|checkbox|radio|submit|reset|file|hidden|image|button [CI]
>       This attribute specifies the type of control to create. The default value for this attribute is "text".

Answer (score -8):

Even if you want to accept numbers for the input, I would recommend using the `text` type.

```
<input type="text" name"some-number" />
```

Client-side run some jQuery validations to verify it's a number.

Then in your server side code, run some validation to verify it is in fact a numerical value.